# Serial communication and richtextbox?

Tags: vb.net

I have a general question concerning serial port communication and storage of the data. When communicating with a serial port (strictly reading from the port in this case) how would one go about storing and manipulating the data in vb.net? For my project I'm doing, I need to take strings from the serial port and then pull numbers from those strings and sort them (numerically, i.e. highest number found at the top and lowest number at the bottom) For some reason in my code I get inner exception errors when I try to move the data from strings to string arrays but I'm determined to figure it out.

As a general question in terms of vb.net programming in relation to serial port communication, is it intelligent to use backgroundworkers? For example, could/should I use a backgroundworker to handle reading from a serial port and then do arithmetic on my data outside of the backgroundworker?

I'm basically just trying to store my data from my serial port into an array, but I don't know how big the array will be that holds the data (i.e. I don't know how many times I'll have data sent to my serial port)

Any tips/info would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: There are too many questions here. Break it down into 2 and open another question for one of them, one is how to read data from the serial port - have you any code?. The other is how to store a set of data of unknown size - you need to use collections - e.g. List(of String).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule if there is going to be any long running task, you should run it in a seperate thread. You do this so that the user experiance is not affected and the GUI stays responsive.

In the case of serial communications there is usually a poll respond architecture which requires constant event handling.

In my experiance I have had great success handling the Interaction with the serial port in a seperate thread that bubbles up events to the GUI. This way I can then process the data to be displayed or stored in another seperate thread and keep the polling running in almost real time.

When I was consuming registers I would store them many different ways but from what you describe, it sounds like the data you are consuming would be best stored in a `List(of String)`.

This structure can be added to almost infinitly and throught the use of predicates can be sorted. The List structure in .net also has a method to convert itself to an array if necessary.

So here is how I can imagine your interaction:

- The GUI thread is started and you initate a connection to your device.
- You then set up a thread that will be receiveing the incoming communications from the device
- In this thread when data is captured it triggers an event in the GUI.
- In the GUI event handler the data is stored in a list and if manipulations need to be preformed on it, they are done in another processing thread that will have a call back handler.
- In the call back you can then display or push the data to its final destination.

The key points are that if you are using a GUI you should absolutly have the communication in a seperate thread to maintian stability of the GUI and create a good user experiance.

Comment: I actually figured out how to do what I wanted on my own, it took forever and I didn't need to use multiple threads after all :P thanks for the help though guys

Comment: I am glad it worked. You should post your solution as an answer, I would be curious to see it.